# JMeter jp@gc-WebDriver Sampler — Graphs Generator

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Hi I am currently with the JMeter Groovy WebDriver. And my question is that having the Graphs Generator imported but don't have any graphs output. Can you please advise the Graphs Generator should works with WebDriver? Or only work for JMeter Sampler Http Request?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graphs Generator listener doesn't really care about the nature of the [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers), it should produce charts no matter of which Samplers are used (as long as they deliver sample results)

The problem is somewhere else, if you pay attention to this red `1` next to yellow exclamation sign at top-right corner of JMeter GUI

[image]

it indicates that at least one error happened during your test so it worth checking [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging), most probably you will find the reason (or at least a clue) there.

Looking at my crystal ball I can see that you don't have [Synthesis Report](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SynthesisReport/) plugin installed which is kind of pre-requisite for the Graphs Generator so my expectation is that if you install it using JMeter Plugins Manager it should resolve your issue.

I would also recommend re-considering the approach to running your tests, GUI mode is supposed to be used for tests development and debugging only, when it comes to tests execution you should [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode.](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode)

And last but not the least, I don't think this Graphs Generator listener adds a lot of value, you can get much better view if you generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

Comment: I have checked the Log and find the below error messages: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kg.apc.jmeter.PluginsCMDWorker Beside I have download and copied the Synthesis Report plugin in the JMeter / LIB/EXT. but not able to find the Synthesis Report from JMETER Listener. Can you please advise? Please kindly review the attached picture 2. Thanks